# What's the best way to print all properties in a list of objects?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Say you had this:

```
class A
{
    public string name;
}
```

And then you have a `List<A>` and want to print the `name` of each object.
Normally, if you wanted to just print the items, you'd do something like

```
String.Join(", ", myList);
```

But I need to print the `name` property, not the `myList` object names. Is there an easier way than a foreach?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
String.Join(", ", myList.Select(x => x.name));
```

For it you have to include `System.Linq` namespace

**EDIT:**

If you want to go for Adam's answer after his code do what this

```
String.Join(", ", myList.Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

**Courtesy Adam Goss comment on answer:**

You wouldn't need to call `.Select(x => x.ToString())` as it would be called internally by object inside `String.Join()`, so if you override `ToString()`, you just call `String.Join(", ", myList);`

So after his code do what you had thought

```
String.Join(", ", myList);
```

Comment: This a very straightforward solution, +1. However, if your class has more properties, I believe that overriding `ToString` is a better idea.

Comment: Isn't the first one cleaner than overriding a generic function?

Comment: @argoneus It is cleaner if you have only 1 property (read my first comment). However, if your class has 2 or more properties (which is a common scenario), overriding `ToString` is better.

Comment: You wouldn't need to call Select(x => x.ToString()) as it would be called internally by object inside String.Join(), so if you override ToString(), you just call String.Join(", ", myList);

Comment: @argoneus: In .Net `.ToString()` method is for creating a custom string of your entity.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the name property, then the best way really would be to override to ToString() method on class A.

```
public override String ToString()
{
    return name;
}
```

If you have more properties, adjust your ToString() to match:

```
public override String ToString()
{
    return String.Format("Name: {0}. Prop1: {1}", name, prop1);
}
```

etc...